# Customizing session timeout per user - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a way to customize the session timeout on a per user basis? It appears that we are going to have to override the `web.config` setting with a custom provider.

Any thoughts on how to do this and potential drawbacks?

Comment: Just store the custom session time in a user record. You can use the ASP.NET Profile Provider.  Then, in [PreRequestHanlderExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.prerequesthandlerexecute.aspx) set `Session.Timeout = userTimeout;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried just editting the user's current session timeout in the `Session_Start` by setting it?

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = yourNewTimeout;
```